# Windows 2003 Server activation Issue

Tags: windows-server-2003

One of our servers was not used for a long time and this has lead to the Windows not booting up due to Activation issue . It asks me to activate windows , but even if I click on "Yes"
the computer just goes back to the login screen where u have to hit ctrl+alt+del to login .
Its like a loop , can anyone tell me what we can do about this issue ? 
I dont want to reinstall the server again .
PS : In safe mode I can login , but I cant activate .
Is there a fix ? like say to remove this checking and make it work .

Comment: Are you sure the box has Internet access?

Comment: It is a HP server so I can access using console , it doesnt connect through Safe Mode with networking only Safe Mode .

Comment: You should also think about accepting some answers if you want people to keep responding.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312295/en-us) article from Microsoft KB.